# Bring Back Unity Button?

Tags: 12.04, unity, gnome

This is probably going to sound really strange but I was probably one of the few people who didn't have issues with Ubuntu 11.04's Unity. It ran great for me, it was super fast, and I thought it looked superb.

I've already done a little bit of Googling and apparently it's impossible to install an old version of Unity, so I was wondering if there was any form of hack to at least bring back the old styling of it (an actual menu bar button instead of the dock icon)

[image]

In theory I could just use the older version (which is what I'd love to do, I loved Natty. Plus it's some nostalgia as it was my first version of Ubuntu) but then I'd be missing out on ALOT of different updates/less security, etc.

Is it possible to at least bring back this button?

PS: the "newer version" would probably be either 12.04 LTS or 13.04/13.10

Answer (score 1):

The system may be unstable, but this is what might work:

1. Uninstall Unity from the newer computer, so `sudo apt-get remove unity` should work if Unity isn't running yet.
2. Run a package manager (such as Synaptic) on the older computer that supports downloading the package without installing it. Download Unity as the newer versions wouldn't be in the 11.04 repositories.
3. Find out where it is and copy it over.
4. Install the package on the new computer. I think Ubuntu Software Center can install .deb packages

If this does work, your system may be unstable and programs are going to crash a lot. However I could be wrong and installing older Unity could be completely fine. If there are problems when installing, you might have to `sudo apt-get remove unity-*`in case some supplemental package isn't deleted from uninstalling.

EDIT: Reading your post again sounds like you found out from searching that what I thought would work didn't, but only you know